# remove trailing zero using awk

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have the following values in my file:

```
1.5000
 0.006
 9.0001
 104.2500
 17.0000
 3.5000
```

I want to remove the trailing zero, the following `awk` will reove the trailing zeros

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /\./){ sub("0*$","",$0); sub ("\\.$","",$0);} print}' file
```

Output of above awk,

```
1.5
 0.006
 9.0001
 104.25
 17
 3.5
```

But I want to add a single zero after the decimal point, I.e. All I want is a float number without trailing zero except values like, 2.0, 3.0

Excepted output

```
1.5
 0.006
 9.0001
 104.25
 17.0
 3.5
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove trailing zeros in a file except character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116528/remove-trailing-zeros-in-a-file-except-character)

Answer (score 1):

Possible with `sed`:

```
sed 's/0\+$//;s/\.$/.0/'
```

If integers like `1200` can occur in the input, handle them separately:

```
sed '/\./{s/0\+$//;s/\.$/.0/;b};s/$/.0/'
```

Comment: `echo 1.0000 | sed 's/0\+$//;s/\.$/.0/'` its not working. below is the output
1.0000

Comment: @Marjer: Outputs `1.0` for me.

Comment: This add `.0` after text.  `echo "test" | sed '/\./{s/0\+$//;s/\.$/.0/;b};s/$/.0/'`

Comment: Duplication symbol `\+` is NOT part of the POSIX definition of _basic_ regular expressions (which is what `sed` uses - _exclusively_ according to the POSIX spec, _by default_ in implementations that provide optional support for _extended_ regexes). **`\+` is therefore not recognized by at least some `sed` implementations (e.g., on OSX)** - its **POSIX-compliant replacement is `\{1,\}`** - for the POSIX def. of a basic regex, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03

Comment: @Marjer: Given that your question is `linux`-tagged, it is, however, curious that the use of `\+` does _not_ work for you, given that Linux uses GNU `sed`, where `\+` _is_ supported. What platform are you on, specifically? What does `sed --version` report?

Answer (score 1):

Use of `sed` is probably simpler in this case:

Note:

- The following uses `sed` with  `-E` (alias of `-r`) to enable support for *extended* regular expressions, which makes the command more readable. It should work with GNU `sed` (Linux) and FreeBSD `sed` (OSX).
- Uses a single substitution command (`s/.../.../`).
- Should there be integers in the input, they are left untouched.

```bsh
sed -E 's/^( *[0-9]+\.[0-9]([0-9]*[1-9])?)0+$/\1/' file
```

- `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end ensure that the *entire* input line is matched
- `*` matches leading spaces, if any
- `[0-9]+\.` matches all digits before the decimal point, plus the decimal point
- `[0-9]` matches the first decimal place (a single digit) - this ensures that a number ending in `.0` isn't stripped of its trailing `0`
- `([0-9]*[1-9])?` matches any additional digits until a *nonzero* digit is encountered, if any
- `0+` then captures trailing zeros through the end of the line
- in the replacement string, `\1` refers to the *1st* capture group (`(...)`), which is everything except the trailing zeros - effectively removing them.
- Note that due to `sed`s default behavior of outputting *all* lines - whether modified or not - lines without matching numbers (numbers that didn't need modification) are simply passed through.

Answer (score 0):

New version that handles better long numbers and text

```
cat file
1.5000
0.006
 9.0001
 104.2500
17.0000
 3.5000
450.0005
test
my00000
```

```
awk '/^ *[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/{sub(/0+$/,"");sub(/\.$/,".0")}1' file
1.5
0.006
 9.0001
 104.25
17.0
 3.5
450.0005
test
my00000
```

This replace all leading `0` with nothing.  If you get `.` at final, replace it with `.0`
It also test if its start with `0` or more space, than number.

Comment: how to modify if the input has string value, if there is a string value i want to leave the string as it is

`echo asd | awk '{a=$0+0;if (a!~/\./) a=a".0";print a}'` it returns 0

Comment: `echo 450.0005  | awk '{a=$0+0;if (a!~/\./) a=a".0";print a}'` it gives output as 450.0

Comment: @Marjer Added a more robust version

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command for more accurate output,

Filename : `sam`

`cat sam`

```
45.0005
0.4440000
45.000000
66.66
44.000
.45000
45
```

```
 awk '{if($0 ~ /^[0-9]*\.[0-9]+/) { sub(/0+$/,"") sub(/\.$/,".0") sub(/^\./,"0.");} else if($0 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) {sub(/$/,".0");}}1' sam
```

Output:

```
45.0005
0.444
45.0
66.66
44.0
0.45
45.0
```

Comment: @Jotne : Please help me to understand the use of number 1 at teh end of the awk

Comment: `1` is a common shorthand for `{ print }` - i.e., the (typically modified) current record is printed unconditionally. The reason this works is that `1` is interpreted as a (Boolean) _pattern_, which always evaluates to true - since this pattern has no associated _action_ (no `{ ... }` block belonging to it), the default action is taken, which is to print.