# Remove trailing zeros in a file except character

Tags: shell, awk

I have the following values in my file:

```
1.5000
0.006
9.0001
104.2500
17.0000
3.5000
paper
```

I want to remove the trailing zero, the following `awk` will remove the trailing zeros but print zeros for character value:

```
awk '{a=$0+0;if (a!~/\./) a=a".0";print a}' file
```

Output of above `awk`:

```
1.5
0.006
9.0001
104.25
17
3.5
0.0
```

How to modify the `awk` to skip the characters?

Excepted output:

```
1.5
0.006
9.0001
104.25
17.0
3.5
paper
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove trailing zero using awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109095/remove-trailing-zero-using-awk)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/,\([0-9]*[.]0\?\)\(\(0*[1-9]\+\)*\)0*/,\1\2/' input
```

This gives:

```
1.5
0.006
9.0001
104.25
17.0
3.5
paper
```

For a multi-column file:

```
awk '$2~/^[0-9]+[.][0-9][1-9]*0+$/{
     $2=gensub(/([.]0?([0-9]*[1-9]+)?)0*$/, "\\1", "g", $2)}1' input
```

Comment: Thanks, how to use the above sed in tab delimited file, incase if input value is 2nd column.

Comment: i have used below `awk -F, '$2~/^[0-9]+[.][0-9][1-9]*0+$/{$2=gensub(/([.]0?([0-9]*[1-9]+)?)0*$/, "\\1", "g", $2)}1' sa.txt ` it prints both the column

Comment: do you want a single column?

Comment: I have the comma separeted file like `1.5000,1.5000` , and i need the awk to check the 2nd column value alone. and prints the result like `1.5000,1.5` . Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55316/discussion-between-marjer-and-perreal).

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk ' {print $2}' yourinputfile | awk ' { sub("\\.*0+$","");print} '
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

```
awk '/^ *[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/{sub(/0+$/,"");sub(/\.$/,".0")}1' file
1.5
0.006
9.0001
104.25
17.0
3.5
paper
```

PS no need to start two equal post:
[remove trailing zero using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109095)

`^ *` Start with `0` or more spaces (you have spaces in some lines)
`[0-9]+` one or more number eks: `5` `545` `34654635`
`\.` a desimal point (`.` needs to be escaped)

`0+$` replace one or more `0` at end of line `$` with nothing
`\.$` if then line ends with `.` add a `0` to get `17.0` and not `17.`

Comment: Thanks @jotne,can you please explan about this awk. i'm bit confused with +\

Comment: @Marjer Updated my post to help out understanding how it works.